Updating geometry by extracting line feature centroid in QGIS
I have two layers, one with polylines and one with points. The layers are related by the field "Netz_ID". I want to write a QML function I can use in QField to update the point geometry of a feature by the centroid of the related polyline. The function should be called by a button I can place in the attribute form.
Does anyone know how to do that?
